# How to filter a file by n. word in line after pattern?

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I've got a large file with diffrent lines.

The lines i am interested in, are looking alike:

```
lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_59 scaffold441.6   99.74   390 1   0   1   390 34065   34454   0.0  715
lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_59 scaffold2333.4  89.23   390 42  0   1   390 3114    2725    1e-138   488
lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_60 scaffold441.6   100.00  186 0   0   1   186 34528   34713   1e-95    344
```

Now i want to get the lines after the pattern 'lcl|NC_' but just if the third word(or the nth word in the line) is smaller than 100.

(In this case the first two lines, since they just got a number of 99.74 and 89.23)

Next they should be saved into a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^lcl\|NC_/ && $3<100' file
lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_59 scaffold441.6   99.74   390 1   0   1   390 34065   34454   0.0  715
lcl|NC_005966.1_gene_59 scaffold2333.4  89.23   390 42  0   1   390 3114    2725    1e-138   488
```

It checks both things:
 - 1st field starting with `lcl|NC_`: `$1 ~ /^lcl\|NC_/` does it. ([Thanks Ed Morton for improving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923284/how-to-filter-a-file-by-n-word-in-line-after-pattern/17923322?noredirect=1#comment26189953_17923322) the previous `$1~"^lcl|NC_"`)
 - 3rd field being <100: `$3<100`.

To save into a file, you can do:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^lcl\|NC_/ && $3<100' file > new_file
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: +1 for the approach but you need to escape the "|" twice, i.e. `$1~"^lcl\\|NC_"` instead of `$1~"^lcl|NC_"`. As written the `|` means "or" as it's an RE metacharacter so it matches lines that start with lcl or contain NC_ and you need to escape it twice or use `[|]` because it's in a string literal and so parsed twice by awk. Actually - you should use /../ instead of "..": `$1~/^lcl\|NC_/` to make it clear you're doing an RE comparison and simplify it a bit.

Comment: Thanks very much for the improvement, @EdMorton ! I haven't noticed the condition I wrote was not good enough. Now that I tested your code, it works like a charm. Just updated my answer.